# Ant target depends on gulp task

Tags: javascript, deployment, ant, gulp, war

I have a `build xml` file in my project which packages my java web app (Java, JavaScript, jsp) into a war file.
There is an empty `post-compile` `target` in the build file.
I would like to have this task minify and concatenate my `js` and amend script tags of the `jsp`s so that they reflect and reference the concatenated files.

I wanted to use gulp to do this (I couldn't find an ant `target` for modifying the `jsp`s appropriately). But how can I then have the subsequent ant task which comes after `post-compile`, only be called upon completion of my gulp tasks (minifying, concatenating and modifying `jsp` script tags)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added a target to my `build.xml` which called gulp (this target "`depends`" on the previous target in my build process (for netbeans found in `build-impl.xml`)):

```
<target depends="-copy-webdir" name="-post-compile">
    <exec vmlauncher="false" executable="gulp" dir="${basedir}"/>
</target>
```

This way I was able to integrate my gulpfile.js into the build process that netbeans generates.

Any suggestions, improvements or comments are still welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @theyuv answer, I updated build.xml in my project as

```
<exec executable="gulp" osfamily="unix" dir="${component.source.dir}">
      <arg line="@{gulpargs}"/>
</exec>
```